# how to exit KeyboadEvent after transition to another frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i'm bulding a flash desktop application where i have a frame (called "Frame1") that contains the following code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
       gotoAndPlay("Frame2");
    }
```

the transition from "Frame1" to "Frame2" happens when the user hits any keyboard button, when the user arrive to "Frame2" he needs to type his name in a text field, but when i type anything in the text field i immediately go back to "Frame1". So, is there a way to exit the KeyboardEvent when i'm at "Frame2" so that the user can use the keyboard to type without firing the KeyboardEvent in "Frame1".

Comment: Just remove the EventListener?

Comment: @DodgerThud remove it from where, because i need it to detect keyboard input.

Comment: Maybe **gotoAndStop**?

Comment: i tried gotoAndStop() but it didn't work, why? But when i removed the listener it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove your listener after it goes to the Frame2:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
       gotoAndPlay("Frame2");
       stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. I found now one small problem in the detection of keyboard input in "Frame1", the code is working fine, but when i open the swf file and hit any key it doesn't detect it, until i click using the mouse, then hit any key then it detects it.

Comment: If you have to use SWF you have to bring the focus to your swf first. But if you export it to Air, you can add your eventListner to NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListner()